# An empty label in assembly occupies memory without having an instruction stored in it?

Tags: assembly, memory, label, byte, mips

If I had the following assembly code:

```
      slt $t0, $t1, $t2
      bgt $t0, $t3, ELSE
      j DONE
ELSE: addi $t0, $t0, 1
DONE:
```

How many bytes would it take in the memory to store it?
More specifically, does the empty "DONE" label use up 4 bytes as any common instruction or does it take 0 bytes since it's empty?

Comment: Labels don't take any storage and they can't be "empty" or "full". They are just bookmarks for a location. The only things taking up space are the instructions (in this example). You can insert an empty line before the `addi` and move the `ELSE` label up there. It would work the same. Or you can label each line with a unique name. Still the same.

Comment: if you are using MARS, you can see in debugger the machine code (+disassembly), i.e. your code after assembling is stored in memory as 5 words `0x012a402a`, `0x0168082a`, `0x14200001`, `0x08100005`, `0x21080001`, with the "ELSE" label pointing at the fifth word (but that information is available only to assembler during assembling, the CPU does have only that `0x14200001` instruction opcode, which is `bne $1, $0, 1`, which makes the jump at the second-next word in memory (next word is `j` instruction, then fifth word is `addi`). (5 words, because `bgt` is implemented as two instructions).

Comment: Related: [Why do we count starting from zero?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/5038).  **Think of labels as referring to the gap between bytes.**

Comment: BTW, you don't need two branches/jumps.  branch to `DONE` on the opposite condition, and remove the `j DONE`.  (so you either jump over or fall-through to the `addi`).  If `$t3` is already booleanized, you can use a more efficient `beq` which isn't a pseudo-instruction (http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html for the basic MIPS I instructions not including pseudo-instructions made out of slt + beq/bne).

Comment: @PeterCordes it was an example/dummy code, I'm not interested that much in the entirety of it, but thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labels do not occupy memory at runtime.  They are just meta data to help the assembler and linker resolve references in your program.  They are not needed to run the program and the CPU doesn't care abut them.  Once the program is linked, they are typically stripped away from the binary as they are no longer needed.

Comment: I have some bad news for you ... as `bgt` is pseudo instruction, it will get assembled `slt + bne`, so in the end that code takes 20 bytes... :-> (+ @Jester :D ) ...

Comment: Actually, `bgt` would be translated to an `slt` and a `bne` instructions, and the `ELSE` instruction also translates to: and `ori` and a `lui` so it's technically 4*6=24 bytes (I believe).

My main issue was the label part. Thanks for answering though

Comment: I am not sure if the `addi` would be 3 instructions, if the immediate part was a big number like `ABCD4321`...

Comment: @Zap as described in your question, the `addi` with immediate `1` is native instruction in single word. If you use larger constant which doesn't fit the 16 bit signed immediate encoding, then the composing may be needed to achieve the desired value. (this is sort of making fun of fuz, because on most of the platforms the assembly is very strict about "what is in source, that is emitted in machine code", MIPS with the many pseudo instructions plus dynamic implementation based on value is not that common, so it is very easy to overlook that)

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you for clarifying

Comment: @Ped7g I don't actually speak MIPS assembly, so I didn't even realize that this is a pseudo instruction...